# "I already was about TO going class tomorrow morning."

Tags: prepositions

I've got the following text from a friend via whatsapp:

> "I already was about TO going class tomorrow morning."

When I read it I'm not sure about its correctness, it says, if the preposition **TO** should be here or not, since it's not clear if this "to" function as a preposition or as a part of infinitive, but both don't make sense to me, because infinitive form is "to"+ "base verb" (without "ing") and the using it as preposition also doesn't make sense since in other cases we say (verb)+ing directly after saying about. (Maybe I would say instead, "I already was about to go to the class tomorrow". Isn't it better?)

Comment: Is your friend a native speaker? If so, haste and/or autocomplete have rendered the quoted sentence ungrammatical for more than one reason.

Comment: No. He is not a native English speaker fortunately, but still normally he speaks English very good.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it addresses a sentence that is severely ungrammatical with uncommon errors. It is unlikely that other people will benefit from discussing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-about-to-do-something):

> **be about to do something**
>   *if someone is about to do something, or if something is about to happen, they will do it or it will happen very soon*
>
> - We were just about to leave when Jerry arrived.
> - Work was about to start on a new factory building.

In this idiom, *to* is the infinitive marker, and it always has to be followed by the infinitive form of the verb.  Because this isn't the preposition *to*, it can't take the *-ing* form of a verb as a complement, so your example is ungrammatical:

> **I already was about **to going class** tomorrow morning.　*(very ungrammatical)*

If we replace it with the infinitive, it's better:

> *I already was about **to go class** tomorrow morning.　*(ungrammatical)*

But it's still ungrammatical because of another problem.  The verb *go* can take a preposition phrase as a locative complement, but *class* isn't a preposition phrase, it's a noun.  We need to indicate a destination with the preposition phrase *to class*:

> I already was about to **go to class** tomorrow morning.　*(OK)*

In this sentence, the first *to* is the infinitive marker introducing *go*, while the second *to* is a preposition marking a location as a destination.  You need both in this sentence.

> I already was about to go to **the** class tomorrow morning.　*(OK)*

Your last example added the word *the*.  This is also grammatical, but whether it's appropriate depends on whether the context licenses it.  Without a special context, most speakers would probably use *class* without a determiner.

---

In this answer:

- The * symbol indicates that an utterance is ungrammatical.
- The ** symbol indicates that an utterance is ungrammatical for multiple reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Can you exaplain me please why "I already was about to go to class tomorrow morning." even without an article?

Comment: @Archimedean_Point Would you consider posting that as a separate question?  I think it's a bit tangential to the main question here, and it might take some time to write a detailed reply.

Comment: Thank you. Done! https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163144/i-already-was-about-to-go-to-no-article-a-the-class-tomorrow-morning