# "I already was about to go to (no article /a /the) class tomorrow morning."

Tags: articles

I was told that it is possible to say:

> "I already was about to go to (no article) class tomorrow morning."

without an article after the the preposition "**to**" before the countable noun "**class**" in this example.

Well, the reason for that is not understood to me, while I obviously understand the difference between the articles "**a**"/"**an**" and "**the**" I don't understand the omitting of all articles here. If it's just non specific class we can say "I already was about to go to a class tomorrow", so why we omit the *indefinite article* here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go to *school, university, classroom, office, and college* etc for a *purpose.* And, this is a regular affair.

So, if the event is regular, and the purpose is clear (of studying), *zero article.*

> Henry and Keith *go to* school

But when you emphasize the *destination/place,* you put an article.

> I am *going to the school* to pick Henry and Keith.

Similarly,

> I *went to hotel* soon after I landed there (for staying purpose)

but...

> I *went to the hotel* to meet Mr Anderson (for specific meeting)

In above all examples, the place is specific and thus, the article *the* is put. But to answer your question, if there is a specific purpose for a specific place (like meeting someone), you may put the article or else, if it's a general event, you omit the article.

[More on zero article is here.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1113_gramchallenge30/)

Comment: I like your explanation of the principle involved but I’ve never come across your (somewhat jarring) example: * I went to Hotel* unless its name follows:*I went to Hotel Central*

Comment: So are there a few examples in which they can be both with article or without, ot it is in any case when the purpose is clear? (hospital, clinic, stadium etc.). I'd like to see a reference for that, if yo don't mind.

Comment: @Archimedean_Point that's straight from my knowledge. No reference. And yes, if that's your usual affair/visit as profession or employee, zero article.

Comment: Whether to use an article or not is also sometimes dependent on dialect.  In the UK and Canada it's common to say that someone "goes to hospital" (no article). In the USA, you *never* omit the article: it's always "goes to *the* hospital."

Comment: @Maulik is the following question has to do something with the principle in your answer or I have to ask a separate question? I read a book which states "Inheritence, age, gender, infectious agents, or behaviours, can all **cause disease**."  Why is there not an article before "disease"?

Comment: @Archimedean_Point that's the same. Zero article!

Comment: But why? What does it has to do with porpuse?

Comment: @Archimedean_Point ah..not purpose...I said yes, it's similar because it has 'zero article.' More on zero articles is here: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1113_gramchallenge30/

Comment: I didn't find there a rull for my question. I think I'll ask about it separatel. Thank you.

Comment: What's about "I'm already on bus."? When I'm talking generally, not anout specific bus, does it also under that classification of porpuse uses?